# Detect when the Filter changes in a Xceed DataGrid control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xceed-datagrid

I'm currently using a Xceed DataGrid control in my C# WPF project. And I need to know when the user changes the filters on the grid so I can update my ViewModel.

Is there a way to detect when the Filters on the grid have been changed?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to filter on the grid: AutoFilterControl and FilterRow.

a) for the AutoFilterControl, you want to subscribe to the AutoFilterValuesChanged event found on DataGridCollectionView

```
<xcdg:DataGridCollectionViewSource AutoFilterValuesChanged="DataGrid_AutoFilterValuesChanged" ... />

private void DataGrid_AutoFilterValuesChanged(object sender, AutoFilterValuesChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(UpdateViewModel), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
}

private void UpdateViewModel()
{
    // your code here
}
```

b) for the FilterRow, somewhere in your code you will have to access the DataGridCollectionView and do the following:

```
var dgCollectionView = dataGrid.ItemsSource as DataGridCollectionView;
if( m_dgCollectionView != null )
{
    foreach( var itemProperty in m_dgCollectionView.ItemProperties )
    {
        PropertyChangedEventManager.AddListener( itemProperty, this, "FilterCriterion" );
    }
}

public bool ReceiveWeakEvent( Type managerType, object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    if( managerType == typeof( PropertyChangedEventManager ) )
    {
        var itemProperty = sender as DataGridItemProperty;
        // your code here
    }

    return true;
}
```

The class that has the listener ("this" in this case) must implement IWeakEventListener.

Every time that a user changes the content of a FilterCell, the FilterCriterion property is updated on the corresponding ItemProperty, which will trigger the weak event for that ItemProperty.